# saving a big array into sql with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, multidimensional-array, tree

I have a 11x84 array that I will fill with 0 and 1. I want to make every possible combination of a 0 and 1 matrix and save them into sql (actually I want to move inside a tree). the result will be huge(2^924),  the program generate the array[11,84] and after making one possible combination should be saved into the database, so later I can read them one by one, and do another calculation over them.

I'm using **c#** and **MsSql 2008**.

I want to know what kind of data should I use for sql database and how my table setup should be?

Do I save each array as a string? it would be a 924 char string. ( 11x84=924 ). Is the string an efficient way?

Or is there a better solution to put the array, as an array into the database? Do I use byte stream or any other kind?

Comment: You need to think about the magnitude of that number, 2 to the 924. That exceeds the number of protons in the entire universe by a truly enormous margin, so you're going to need to find another universe in which to build your hard disk.

Comment: Instead of storing it, can you simply calculate the value when needed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this data and your calculations?  Perhaps there's a way to do it that doesn't require 2^924 records.

Comment: 2^924 is WAYYYY above 2^256.
Were not even close.
The size of the Universe you would need for that is staggering.

Comment: 3885337784451458140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 KB ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: This could be the greatest question I've ever seen.

Answer (score 8):

so if you have a 924-char string, and plan on creating all possible 1 and 0 values in it, then you will have 2^924 BYTES of data to hold, which would equate to appx 10^254 times the size of the internet today.

But I'm sure you want to know how long this would take too.

Assuming you want this to be done anytime soon, we'll use the fastest supercomputer in the world to date, the Tianhe-2, which does 33,860 trillion calculations per second.  Assuming generating a SINGLE number takes only 1 calculation (which, by the way, is a huge underestimate), we are looking at appx 10^261 seconds, or appx 10^251 millenia.

Getting close!

So, assuming (unbelievably roughly) we declare an eon to be 500 million years, we are looking at appx. 10^245 eons.  If we take one assumption of string theory's cyclic universe (http://discovermagazine.com/2008/apr/25-3-theories-that-might-blow-up-the-big-bang#.UcCgovnqneo), which would occur every trillion years or so (so every 2000 eons), we find that appx. 10^242 recreations of the universe will have taken place by the time you are finished with your data calculation.

"But I don't want to wait that long!"

Well I have good news.  Using these numbers (and this is where my math gets fuzzy), we have 10^242 recreations of the universe.  There are appx `365 days * 500 million years * 2000 eons` per recreation, so around a total of 3.65 * 10^256 days for this to complete. So, when we take `(3.65 * 10^256) mod 365`, we find out that it will take exactly 0 days to complete your task, assuming you started 10^242 recreations of the universe ago.

Hope you will-have brought some pizza, cause you will-have been gotten hungry (it's so difficult talking about tenses in this quantum world of ours).

**AUTHOR'S NOTE:** This assumes a char array.  If a bit array is used, all calculations may be computed using a base number of 2^921 (1 bit per "char" instead of 8), thereby shortening the calculation.

Comment: I'm not following the point of the last paragraph

Comment: @Jonesy: pizza paragraph updated to take into account future-past-participle tense.

Comment: lol damnit the one before that i meant.

Comment: @Jonesy: According to one version of the repeating universe theory, when the universe repeats, the exact same course of events will happen each time.  I made a playful but unspoken assumption that the asker operated by the laws of the universe, but could also exist outside those laws.  That paragraph, then, is to demonstrate that, had he started that long ago, the asker's computation would in fact be finishing just now.  Since we assume this is a cyclic universe, we can assume this iteration is NOT the first.  Once assuming that, we can see that given any sufficient depth, and 0 time...

Comment: @Jonesy (cont.): ... the moment the asker begins the calculation, that same calculation will FINISH from a previous recreation, and so he will have the results instantly.  Storing them, on the other hand, is a problem I chose not to address, since others already had done so.

Comment: This is the most well thought out sarcastic answer ever. +1.

Comment: The time factor is *completely irrelevant*. There is not enough space in the Universe to store the data.

Comment: @Jason: yes, thank you.  I realize that.  Hence the "10^254 times the size of the internet" comment.  Everyone else was focusing on the size, while ignoring the time element, which is why I focused on that.

Comment: @Russell Uhl: Yes, I appreciate that, but "10^254 times the size of the Internet conveys that it's large", but it doesn't convey that it's *impossibly* large unless your reader already knows that there are *only* 10^80 protons in the Universe.

Comment: @Jason: I get that.  Again, the biggest reason I didn't address the issue is because the asker would have figured it out pretty darned quickly by all the flack in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to store this kind of data, I think most compact form would be a BitArray, see here for a ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx

Buuuut, if your calculation is right (and I think it is), then you would end up with 1,4181298336770849826794266683101e+278 possibilities.

Each one using at least 924 bit (~ 116 byte) sums up to about: 
1,4961466213803019672087747815019e+268 TB (TerraByte), which not all harddrives on earth together may store! Sorry about that....